# Select part of txt in python

Tags: python, list, file, txt

[txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/negJ6.png)I have a .txt file, from this I should extrapolate only some parts (the file has times, places and other info relating to events, but also other writings that do not interest me), how can I automatically select ONLY the parts what do i need?
I leave you an idea that doesn't seem to work (this would be just the beginning as there would be more information to extrapolate).
Thank you all

Comment: Can you post a portion of your file and specify which values you which to select?

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can post a small part of the txt file, we will be able to better understand what kind of procedures can be done in the script to get the data you want.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

You can use the split() function. If you have a string named `text` and know that each part that you want is separated by a newline (for example), you can use `text.split(“\n”)`, which returns a list of strings that are separated by newline characters. You can then process this list further to find the information/words you’re looking for.